# Base64 image with charset=utf-8; not displayed in Ionic2

Tags: angular, character-encoding, ionic2

I'm migrating my application with camera from Ionic1 to Ionic2.

It turns out that that specifying a charset=utf-8; in a base64 URI will result as a non displayed image.

Not working:

```
string imgURI:string = 'data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,...'
```

Working:

```
string imgURI:string = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...'
```

I tried to display that imgURI as

```
<img [src]="imgURI"/>
<img src="{{imgURI}}"/>
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="imgURI"/>
```

each time faced the same result aka imgURI not correctly displayed. Seems that the '-' in the charset 'utf-8' breaks the evaluation of the value.

do I make something wrong? anyone got an idea how to specify the charset of a base64 image in Ionic2?

Comment: you should use file path instead of base64 for better performance

Comment: on a mobile device with cordova I find much more convenient to work with base64. Furthermore, what are your sources for your thought?

Comment: /**
 * Warning: Using DATA_URL is not recommended! The DATA_URL destination
 * type is very memory intensive, even with a low quality setting. Using it
 * can result in out of memory errors and application crashes. Use FILE_URI
 * or NATIVE_URI instead.
 */

read more here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: thx gonna have a look! p.s.: my question remains still open